# Passing parameters with h:commandButton -- or the equivalent

Tags: jsf-2

I read on other threads that this does not work:

```
<h:commandButton value="Create New Account" 
                action="#{acctBean.doCreate}" >
   <f:param name="acctName" value="#{acctBean.handle}" />
   <f:param name="acctNo" value="#{acctBean.id}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

The `doCreate()` method will return a navigation to a "congratulations" page if it creates the account. The target page can then resolve `#{param.handle}` and `#{param.id}`.

I know this will work if I use `h:commandLink` instead, but I want a button, not a link.  Is there any generally accepted way of doing that?

UPDATE:

Based on the first answer from @BalusC I created the following test code:

```
<h:commandButton value="Push Me" action="goAcctCreated" >
    <f:param name="acctName" value="This Is Account Name" />
    <f:param name="acctNo" value="1234" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:button value="Push Me #2" outcome="newAcct" >
    <f:param name="acctName" value="This Is Account Name" />
    <f:param name="acctNo" value="1234" />
</h:button>
```

And in the target page I have:

```
<p>You may now log in with the account you just created: <b>#{param['acctName']}</b>.</p>
<p>This is account number <b>#{param['acctNo']}</b>.</p>
```

As before, the `h:commandButton` does not work with a POST transaction and as BalusC said, `h:button` does a GET and does work.

Interestingly enough, on the POST that the `h:commandbutton` does it has the parameters encoded, as viewed by Firebug:

```
acctName    This Is Account Name
acctNo  1234
javax.faces.ViewState   8642267042811824055:-4937858692781722161
testForm    testForm
testForm:j_idt55    testForm:j_idt55
```

So the `f:param` tags are doing their job at least, but the target page doesn't resolve the EL expressions `#{param[xxx]}`.  They also don't show up in the scoped variables report (ctrl-shift-D).   Is there something I am supposed to do on the target page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work perfectly fine on JSF 2.x. Did you ever try it yourself? If it doesn't work, then you're either *actually* using JSF 1.x or you're sending a redirect after POST.

The other threads which you're referring to were undoubtely talking about JSF 1.x, when the [`<f:param>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/param.html) was indeed not supported on [`<h:commandButton>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html). On JSF 1.x, you would have used `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` instead or some shot of CSS to style the `<h:commandLink>` to look like a button.

E.g.

```html
<h:commandLink styleClass="button" ...>
```

with

```
a.button {
    display: inline-block;
    background: lightgray;
    border: 1px outset lightgray;
    outline: none;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: default;
}
a.button:active {
    border-style: inset;
}
```

Note that in JSF 2.x you've also the opportunity to use the new [`<h:button>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/button.html) which fires a GET request instead of a POST request. This is better if you don't need to execute any bean action (i.e. your current action is just returning a plain navigation case outcome) and want the request to be idempotent.

```
<h:button value="Create New Account" outcome="create">
    <f:param name="acctName" value="#{acctBean.handle}" />
    <f:param name="acctNo" value="#{acctBean.id}" />
</h:button>
```

This will navigate to `create.xhtml` with the given parameters in request URL.

Comment: Well I did try my original code and it didn't work. That's why I started looking to see why it wouldn't work.  I didn't realize it was a JSF 1.x problem that had been fixed in JSF.2.    I looked in the Firebug network trace and I didn't see the parameters submitted.   I'll try it again.

Comment: Perhaps you're running JSF 2.x in JSF 1.x compatibility modus? E.g. faces-config incorrectly declared as 1.x. Note that this was never intented to work in JSF 1.x, so there was nothing to fix. The JSF 1.x way would be using `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`. They just added the `<f:param>` support in `<h:commandButton>` in JSF 2.x.

Comment: As per your update, it should work perfectly fine. To be sure, I just tested it here with Mojarra 2.1.3 on Tomcat 7.0.19 and Glassfish 3.1. Apparently you're somewhere redirecting the request by `?faces-redirect=true`? Maybe in action method or in a custom navigation handler? A redirect instructs the browser to fire brand new GET request.

Comment: Argh!   That was it.  I had a **redirect** tag in the navigation case in faces-config.xml. I take that out and it works.  If you post this as a new answer I'll give it a green-check.

Comment: The first paragraph already covers that. By the way, navigation cases are soo JSF 1.x. Are you aware of the new implicit navigation feature?

Comment: I am but I resist trendiness.   I suppose since my application isn't finished yet I will go ahead and convert this one.