# Encoding request parameters after JSF2.0 Post-Redirect-Get

Tags: java, jsf-2

I've upgraded a JSF application from 1.1 to 2.0 and I'm trying to encode request parameters after performing an action.

The situation:

- The user presses a save-button on viewA.xhtml which invokes save() on a backing bean A. After the save() is performed successfully I navigate to  **viewB.xhtml?faces-redirect=true**.
- View B, which is navigated to, defines a couple of view parameters (f:viewParam).
- The two views currently have to use different backing beans.
- The button must be a commandButton such that a action method is invoked prior to the navigation so I cannot use a regular button with f:param elements.

I found another issue already solved [Passing parameters with h:commandButton -- or the equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366480/passing-parameters-with-hcommandbutton-or-the-equivalent) but I'm dependent on the **redirect**.

Comment: How did you do it in JSF 1.1? It would not be possible in JSF 1.1 as well without manually passing the params in redirect URL and nothing is different in that in JSF 2.0.

Comment: In JSF 1.1, the application had widespread use of settings put into session scoped contexts. Back then, everything was POST, as you know, and to be able to make full use of partial page rendering, enable bookmarking and improve performance I try to convert as much of the navigation as possible into GET requests, implementing the Post-Redirect-Get pattern wherever possible. Navigating around is now a breeze as long as I use h:commandLink or h:button along with f:param.

Comment: Why do you not just pass those parameters through the redirect URL?

Comment: Well, I actually had not tried because: 1) I though it could not be done to mix faces parameters with ordinary request parameters and 2) there had to be more elegant "best practice".

Comment: Well, as you know, the solution works perfectly. I'd give you credit, but there's no actual response. Heh. Thanks. :)

Comment: I did not immediately post an answer because it was not immediately clear what you're struggling with. I'll repost it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass those parameters along in the redirect URL.

```
String outcome = String.format(
    "viewB?faces-redirect=true&amp;foo=%s&amp;bar=%s",
        URLEncoder.encode(foo, "UTF-8"),
        URLEncoder.encode(bar, "UTF-8"));

return outcome;
```